# Error while creating a Membership user "The password-answer supplied is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

I tried creating a new user using CreateUser method. but when I click create user button I get this weird error :  "The password-answer supplied is invalid".

I already tried putting a strong password (123$567) or a normal password(1234).
I doubt it has anything to do with the password strength because that would throw a different exception.

Here is my code:

```
Membership.CreateUser(username, password);
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 10):

In your web.config you probably have the setting

```
<system.web>
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <add bla="bla" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" ...
```

Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Using @spender's tip (+1) I found the below worked for me by explicitly stating requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" in the web.config (I had to add the attribute).  I then found I could just use Membership.CreateUser(userName, password, email); to create my user.

```
<system.web>  
<membership>  
    <providers>  
        <add bla="bla" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to set parameters in web.config

```
<system.web>
<membership>
    <providers>
<add name="YOURMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="con"  minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" applicationName="YourAppName" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="2147483647"/>
```

I tried this. Its working Fine.
Thanks